# PHP: Librería Zebra Pagination y URLs

Tags: php, paginación

Estoy intentando usar la librería [Zebra Pagination](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Pagination/) para paginar una sección de mi web. He logrado hacerlo, pero tengo un problema con la URL.

Uso un archivo .htaccess para embellecer mi URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc/error/index

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controlador=$1&accion=$2
    
</IfModule>
```

De manera que mi URL se ve tal que `url_base/controlador/accion`.

La sección que estoy paginando es `url_base/listas/clasificacion`, de manera que al paginar habría de quedar `url_base/listas/clasificacion&page=x`, siendo x la página en cuestión que se está visualizando en ese momento.

Sim embargo, el controlador de la paginación que añade la librería a mi web no funciona como espero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si entro a `url_base/listas/clasificacion` y hago clic en el controlador para ir a la segunda página, en vez de llevarme a `url_base/listas/clasificacion&page=2` me lleva a `url_base/listas/clasificacion?controlador=listas&accion=clasificacion&page=2`, y sigo viendo la página 1.

Es decir, en vez de añadir simplemente `&page=2` añade también otra vez el controlador y la acción "sin embellecer", `?controlador=listas&accion=clasificacion`.

¿Se os ocurre cuál puede ser el problema?

**EDICIÓN:**

He encontrado la función de la librería que parece controlar el asunto:

```
/**
 *  The base URL to be used when generating the navigation links.
 *
 *  This is helpful for the case when the URL where the records are paginated may have parameters that are not needed
 *  for subsequent requests generated by pagination.
 *
 *  For example, suppose some records are paginated at `https://yourwebsite/mypage/`. When a record from the list is
 *  updated, the URL could become something like `https://youwebsite/mypage/?action=updated`. Based on the value of
 *  `action` a message would be shown to the user.
 *
 *  Because of the way this script works, the pagination links would become
 *
 *  `https://youwebsite/mypage/?action=updated&page=[page number]`
 *
 *  when {@link method} is `get` and {@link variable_name} is `page`
 *
 *  `https://youwebsite/mypage/page[page number]/?action=updated`
 *
 *  when {@link method} is `url` and {@link variable_name} is `page`
 *
 *  As a result, whenever the user would paginate, the message would be shown to him again and again because
 *  `action` will be preserved in the URL!
 *
 *  The solution is to set the `base_url` to `https://youwebsite/mypage/` and in this way, regardless of how the URL
 *  changes, the pagination links will always be in the form of
 *
 *  `https://youwebsite/mypage/?page=[page number]`
 *
 *  when {@link method} is `get` and {@link variable_name} is `page`
 *
 *  `https://youwebsite/mypage/page[page number]/`
 *
 *  when {@link method} is `url` and {@link variable_name} is `page`
 *
 *  Of course, you may still have query strings in the value of the `base_url` if you wish so, and these will be
 *  preserved when paginating.
 *
 *  >   If you need to preserve the hash in the URL, make sure to include the zebra_pagination.js file in your page!
 *
 *  @param  string      $base_url                   (Optional) The base URL to be used when generating the navigation
 *                                                  links
 *
 *                                                  Defaults is whatever returned by
 *                                                  {@link https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}
 *
 *  @param  boolean     $preserve_query_string      (Optional) Indicates whether values in query strings, other than
 *                                                  those set in `base_url`, should be preserved
 *
 *                                                  Default is `TRUE`
 *
 *  @return void
 */
public function base_url($base_url = '', $preserve_query_string = false) {

    // we'll need this in case "variable_name" is an empty string
    // (when "base_url" must be explicitly declared)
    $this->_properties['base_url_explicit'] = $base_url !== '';

    // set the base URL
    $base_url = ($base_url == '' ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $base_url);

    // parse the URL
    $parsed_url = parse_url($base_url);

    // cache the "path" part of the URL (that is, everything *before* the "?")
    $this->_properties['base_url'] = rtrim($parsed_url['path'], '/');

    // cache the "query" part of the URL (that is, everything *after* the "?")
    $this->_properties['base_url_query'] = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? $parsed_url['query'] : '';

    // store query string as an associative array
    parse_str($this->_properties['base_url_query'], $this->_properties['base_url_query']);

    // should query strings (other than those set in $base_url) be preserved?
    $this->_properties['preserve_query_string'] = $preserve_query_string;

}
```

Al cambiar el parámetro de entrada `$preserve_query_string` de `true` a `false` deja de añadir el controlador y la acción, lo cual es un avance, pero agrega la página con `?` en vez de con `&`, así: `url_base/listas/clasificacion?page=x` en vez de así: `url_base/listas/clasificacion&page=x`, con lo cual tampoco funciona.

**EDICIÓN 2:**

Le he mandado un correo al creador de la librería y me dice que es obligatorio que la cadena comience por `?`, que ha de tratarse de un problema con mi .htaccess.

**EDICIÓN 3:**

Adjunto el HTML de la paginación. Lo he sacado directamente de la consola del navegador, porque en mi código únicamente le digo a la librería que aplique el método `render()` sobre mi objeto `$paginacion`:

```
if($elementos_totales > $elementos_por_pagina) //Controlador de la páginación
{
    $paginacion->labels('<<', '>>');
    $paginacion->render();
}
```

El HTML:

```
<div class="Zebra_Pagination">
    <ol class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link">&lt;&lt;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a href="/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc/listas/clasificacion" class="page-link">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc/listas/clasificacion?pagina=2" class="page-link">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc/listas/clasificacion?pagina=2" class="page-link">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Ahora tiene este aspecto por algunas modificaciones que le he hecho al CSS, además del cambio de `labels`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que la clave está aquí, pero desde mi código creo que no tengo posibilidad de acceder a este enlace, lo genera automáticamente el método:

```
<a href="/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc/listas/clasificacion?pagina=2" class="page-link">2</a>
```

**EDICIÓN 4:**

Creo haber encontrado la función que genera el enlace:

```
/**
 *  Generate the link for the page given as argument.
 *
 *  @return void
 */
private function _build_uri($page) {

    // if page propagation method is through SEO friendly URLs
    if ($this->_properties['method'] == 'url') {

        // see if the current page is already set in the URL
        // when "variable_name" is an empty string we'll also factor in "base_url" (which is mandatory in this case)
        if (preg_match(
            '/\b' . str_replace('/', '\/', preg_quote(($this->_properties['variable_name'] === '' ? $this->_properties['base_url'] . '/' : '') . $this->_properties['variable_name'])) . '([0-9]+)\b/i',
            $this->_properties['variable_name'] === '' ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $this->_properties['base_url']
        ) > 0) {

            // build string
            $url = str_replace('//', '/', preg_replace(

                // replace the currently existing value
                // (also handle the case when "variable_name" is an empty string)
                '/\b' . str_replace('/', '\/', preg_quote(($this->_properties['variable_name'] === '' ? $this->_properties['base_url'] . '/' : '') . $this->_properties['variable_name'])) . '([0-9]+)\b/i',

                // if on the first page and we are avoiding duplicate content, remove page number
                // (also handle the case when "variable_name" is an empty string)
                ($this->_properties['variable_name'] === '' ? $this->_properties['base_url'] . '/' : '') . ($page == 1 && $this->_properties['avoid_duplicate_content'] ? '' : $this->_properties['variable_name'] . $page),

                // handle the case when "variable_name" is an empty string
                $this->_properties['variable_name'] === '' ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $this->_properties['base_url']

            ));

        // if the current page is not yet in the URL, set it, unless we're on the first page
        // case in which we don't set it in order to avoid duplicate content
        } else $url = ($this->_properties['variable_name'] !== '' ? $this->_properties['base_url'] . '/' : '') . $this->_properties['variable_name'] . $page;

        // handle trailing slash according to preferences
        $url = rtrim($url, '/') . ($this->_properties['trailing_slash'] ? '/' : '');

        // if values in the query string - other than those set through base_url() - are not to be preserved
        // preserve only those set initially
        if (!$this->_properties['preserve_query_string']) $query = implode('&', $this->_properties['base_url_query']);

        // otherwise, get the current query string
        else $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        // return the built string also appending the query string, if any
        $uri =  $url . ($query != '' ? '?' . $query : '');

    // if page propagation is to be done through GET
    } else {

        // if values in the query string - other than those set through base_url() - are not to be preserved
        // preserve only those set initially
        if (!$this->_properties['preserve_query_string']) $query = $this->_properties['base_url_query'];

        // otherwise, get the current query string, if any, and transform it to an array
        else parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);

        // if we are avoiding duplicate content and if not the first/last page (depending on whether the pagination links are shown in natural or reversed order)
        if (!$this->_properties['avoid_duplicate_content'] || ($page != ($this->_properties['reverse'] ? $this->_properties['total_pages'] : 1)))

            // add/update the page number
            $query[$this->_properties['variable_name']] = $page;

        // if we are avoiding duplicate content, don't use the "page" variable on the first/last page
        elseif ($this->_properties['avoid_duplicate_content'] && $page == ($this->_properties['reverse'] ? $this->_properties['total_pages'] : 1))

            unset($query[$this->_properties['variable_name']]);

        // make sure the returned HTML is W3C compliant
        $uri = htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($this->_properties['base_url']) . (!empty($query) ? '?' . http_build_query(array_map('urldecode', $query)) : ''));

    }

    // if for whatever reason the URI is an empty string it means it should be pointing to the root ("/")
    // we can't leave this as an empty string or it will point to whatever URL is currently open in the browser
    return $uri !== '' ? $uri : '/';

}
```

**EDICIÓN 5:**

He probado a sustituir `'?'` por `'&'` en las dos líneas en las que aparece y, bueno, funciona bien la primera vez que haces clic en un botón, pero luego continúa añadiendo `&pagina=x` a lo loco, con lo cual acabas con una URL poco estética:

```
url_base/listas/clasificacion&pagina=2&pagina=3&pagina=4&pagina=3&pagina=2
```

Salen más de dos páginas porque he probado a disminuir el número de elementos por página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, es imposible volver a la primera página, ya que habría de ser simplemente:

```
url_base/listas/clasificacion
```

Comment: Creo que deberías revisar un poco la teoría de los Query params, ya que estos siempre inician con **?** para su primer parámetro y luego se usa el **&** para los demás. Es por esto que **url_base/listas/clasificacion&page=x** no es válido, más si lo sería **url_base/listas/clasificacion?page=x**

Comment: El asunto es que con `&` sí cambia de página y con `?`, no. No es que tenga preferencia por uno u otro, yo lo que quiero es que funcione.

Comment: Creo que puedes solucionar usando la solucion propuesta por el Script o con htaccess `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2/$3.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^clasificacion/(.*) clasificacion.php?page=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.php%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Hola, Jose. Gracias por tu comentario, te agradecería si lo pudieras agregar de forma más detallada como respuesta.

Comment: Podrias mostrar el HTML de la paginación?

Comment: Sí, edito el mensaje original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era tan sencilla como añadir `[QSA]` al `RewriteRule`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/recopilatorios/php/web/mvc/error/index

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controlador=$1&accion=$2 [QSA]
    
</IfModule>
```

150 puntos de reputación evaporados después, ni tan mal.